# Plotting complex number error... |z−2|<1

Tags: plotting, complex

```
z[x_, y_] := x + yi
f[z_] := {1/(z - 1)};
RegionPlot[{(x - 2)^2 + y^2}^1/2 < 1, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

**|Z−2|<1**

I am new to Mathematica and i would like to know how to plot a complex function |z−2|<1. codes is written by me, but it won't work...

Comment: Not at a computer right now, so: `ParametricPlot[ReIm[2 + r Exp[I θ]], {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]`

Answer (score 1):

Writing:

```
RegionPlot[Norm[(x + I y) - 2] < 1, {x, 0, 4}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

I get:

[image]

that is as desired.

Comment: thank you very much...!!